# Interacting with a file dialog

Tags: python, html, splinter

I wish to use splinter to browse after a file and open it. I have managed to open the dialog in firefox but I don't know how to interact with it. For example, how do I select a file and choose "open". Do the elements in a file dialog have names with regard to html?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. You can simulate this using the fill method for the file input field. So something like:

```
browser.find_by_id('file_input').fill(path-to-file)
```